# Openbravo Point of Sales: Tax after a certain amount

Tags: point-of-sale, openbravo

I'm using an [Openbravo](http://www.openbravo.com/product/pos/) open-source PoS. Is it possible to setup Openbravo PoS to apply a tax only after a certain amount? For example, if the total is less than or equal to $10 then there is no tax, but if the total is over $10 then a 8% tax is applied.

For example, if the item costs $10 then the total is $10. If the item is $10.01 then the total is $10.81.

Answer (score 1):

when creating products in Openbravo POS you can define for each item the type of tax that will be applied to it.

Then, you can create "Tax exempt" category with rate 0% and apply it to those items under $10. For the rest, you should create another tax category to apply the rate of 8%.

Hope this helps,

Elena

Comment: The goal is tax exempt the TOTAL when it is less than $10.

For example two items that cost $4 and $10 are tax exampt.